# How can I write my own function that calculate cosine similarity for each row in a matrix as a given 2 parameters in language R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, text-mining, data-science

Here is my codes below.ı just able to done for compare 2 vectors and now ı want to build a function.

```
library('lsa')
td = tempfile()
dir.create(td)
write( c("HDa","2Pb","2","BxU","BuQ","Bve"), file=paste(td, "D1", sep="/"))
write( c("HCK","2Pb","2","09","F","G"), file=paste(td, "D2", sep="/"))


myMatrix = textmatrix(td, minWordLength=1)
res <- lsa::cosine(myMatrix[,1], myMatrix[,2])
res
#0.3333
```

and here is part of my matrix has 266 rows and 6 columns

```
      ios d.0 d.1 d.2 d.3 d.4 d.5
1   190371877 HDa 2Pb   2 BxU BuQ Bve
2   190890807 HCK 2Pb   2  09   F   G
3   193999742 HDa 2Pb   2 1wL 1ye    
4   192348099 HDa 2Pb   2 2WP        
5   194907960 HDa 2Pb   2   Y   F   G
6   194306872 HDa 2Pb   2 2WP        
7   190571682 HDa 2Pb   2   i   F   C
8   195878080 HDa 2Pb   2   Y   F   G
9   195881580 HDa 2Pb   2   Y   F   G
10  193746161 HDa 2Pb   2 1wL
```

I have a matrix 266 row and 7 column like above.First column is my product's id and the others are product's definitive tags. If ı want to have my own function and give a 2 input one is a definitive tag vector(like c("HDa","2Pb","2","BxU","BuQ","Bve")) and the other is a product id(ios). As a result I want to see true or false(1 or 0) among top 8 product which most similar to product id's vector.if top 8 products contains product id that given as a parameter is gonna be true else false

Can anyone explain how to solve my problem?

Comment: I'm not giving a concrete answer because the question is specifically R programming. Just forwarding you to a pair of questions here: how to [compute matrix of some binary-data similarity using matrix algebra](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/49453/3277), and [formulas for selected binary-data similarities](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/61910/3277) (including cosine = Ochiai).